# Is it possible to make a HTML chart modifiable?

Tags: html, charts

im totally new when it comes to trying to make HTML code.  I was wondering if its possible to make certain rows/columns in a HTML chart modifiable by random users that view the page.

And if so is it possible to make it so that once modified they click a button and it changes some other rows like a calculator does, based on what i have preset (numbers)

hopefully that makes sense...

thks

btw im using a Google site i made

Comment: What do you mean by chart? A table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<input>` elements for allowing people to input text, and javascript for any computation involving their contents, or for changing what's on the page.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript for more info on each of these.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tables are columns and rows of static data, not modifiable. One solution would be using javascript and do an .onClick method on each `<td>`. That method would convert text in  to something like `<input type="text" name="cell_x_y" value="original_value" />` and then another method which would handle ENTER key or leaving that text field and would submit value to server.